# Как получить результат plural внутри ts файла?(статически это ,вроде, называется)

Tags: angular, typescript

Есть такой плюрал.

```
 export class I18nPluralPipeComponent {
  messages: any[] = ['Message 1'];
  messageMapping:
      {[k: string]: string} = {'=0': 'No messages.', '=1': 'One message.', 'other': '# messages.'};
}
```

чтобы он работал в HTML нужно его добавить в шаблон

```
  template: `<div>{{ messages.length | i18nPlural: messageMapping }}</div>`
```

В итоге на странице покажет результат one message. Я хочу чтобы эта запись работала в ts файле.

```
let str =  `${{ messages.length | i18nPlural: messageMapping }}`
```

Но он ругается. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Импортировать его в модуль

```
import { I18nPluralPipe } from '@angular/common';

 providers: [
    I18nPluralPipe,
   },
],
```

импортировать в компоненте

```
import { I18nPluralPipe } from '@angular/common';
```

вызвать

```
constructor(
        private i18nPlural: I18nPluralPipe,
    ) {}
```

использовать дальше

```
public arrForDocument: { [k: string]: string } = { one: 'документ', few: 'документа', many: 'документов', other: 'документов' };


let length = rows.length;
    let srt = this.i18nPlural.transform(length, this.arrForDocument);
```